# How to understand different usages of "across"?

Tags: grammar

I always have a problem understanding different usages of the word. I have a naive idea that across a road or a river means from one side to the other side. But sometimes it is not clear what it means, for example - "The light from across the summit is clear; but the shadows are slanting and deep on the slope of the dark valley."
What does across mean here? Could you also please provide other instances of the word being used so as to clarify the meaning to me?

Answer (score 1):

**across** can refer to traversing a space:

> They walked across the desert.
>
> They walked across the courtyard.
>
> The clouds flew across the sky as the storm approached.
>
> A new modern bridge will go across the river here.

Or it can refer to the location of something which is situated on the far side of the space between the speaker and that thing:

> The store across the street sells tea.
>
> The people living in the land across the river speak French.

We can speak of things as originating at a place located on the far side of such a space, using "from across".

> The bright light *from across* the street makes it impossible to sleep; it shines in my window.
>
> People come *from across* the country to visit the monument.

Comment: what does the sentence "People come from across the country to visit the monument." mean ? I can't understand :((

Comment: They come with the purpose of visiting the monument. Where do they come from?  "From across the country", that is, they begin their journeys at different places throughout the country, each according to where his or her home town happens to be.

Comment: Can I rewrite that sentence like this: people from across the country come to visit the monument ?

Comment: Grammatically your sentence is OK. "People from across the street come to eat at this restaurant." "People from across the street come to shop at this market."

Answer (score 0):

The word 'across' is indicating the position something is in relation to, as in from one side to another.

I.e. We sat across from one another  - this means that two people were sitting apart from each other - on either side.

I.e. We sailed across the Atlantic ocean - sailing from one point across to the other side of the ocean.

I.e. We walked across the bridge - starting at one end of a bridge walking to the other end.